# Can't set privileges in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

I tried this:

```
SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER = ON
MySQL said: Documentation
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

This is my second attempt:

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user '*********'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Again I tried this:

```
UPDATE `USER_PRIVILEGES` SET `PRIVILEGE_TYPE`='ALL',`IS_GRANTABLE`='YES' WHERE 1
in the information schema user privileges
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'infografix'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Somebody please help me. I tried every thing nothing works for me.

Comment: If you don't already have super privileges, you can't give them to yourself. This needs to be done by an account that already has super privileges, usually the `root` account.

Comment: I said "usually". I believe that's the default super account.

Comment: I have all privileges on the database including 
 ALL PRIVILEGES
 ALTER  CREATE
 CREATE ROUTINE  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
 CREATE VIEW  DELETE
 DROP  EXECUTE
 INDEX  INSERT
 LOCK TABLES  REFERENCES
 SELECT  SHOW VIEW
 TRIGGER  UPDATE
, i am the root user, and i want to add an event to my subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a phpMyAdmin issue, but a MySQL rights & privileges issue. You need to login to MySQL as a user who can grant privileges—via `GRANT`—to run the commands you are running successfully.

Comment: But how to login to MySQL from CPANEL. The problem lies in the WEBSERVER not in the local system.It works in the local pc well.